# C++ point to Object

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object, inheritance

How can I check if an element from an array of pointers to another class points to an Object from another class?

```
class A  {

    //some code hier

    };

    class B : A {

    B ob;

    };

    class C: B, A {

    A* array[100];

    void check() {

    if (ob* array[100])  {    // ???
    //do something

      }

    }
};
```

Comment: You type `B` contains an instance of itself, which is not supported. Your members and inheritance are entirely private.

Comment: A class can't have a member whose type is that same class. `class B { B ob; };` ain't gonna fly.

Comment: I'm unclear what you intend for `ob* array[100]` to mean.

Comment: You can use a `std::vector` or some other container and not have null items.

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. What do you **really** want? What is the purpose of A, B, C and ob? Why do you want to use pointers?

Comment: @JHBonarius It's part of an assigment it's not very clear for me to, the main thing is to check if an Element from an Array of Pointers that is defined in Class C points to an Object from class B.

Comment: @kik see `dynamic_cast` read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: You don't really say what you are trying to accomplish and your code doesn't show your intent.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis  Here is the full assigment for this specific topic, but it's still a part of another bigger assigment. 

The function RemoveBannedGoods () examines each element of the warehouse as follows: Otherwise it is checked if the element points to an object of the class MilkProduct. If this is the case, the expiration date of the product is checked. If this is smaller / older (operator <) than today's date, the product must be removed from the warehouse.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis  I'm not showing my intent, because the assigment in not very clear for me also.

Answer (score 0):

*If* the class is polymorphic (i.e. it contains at least one virtual function), then you can test whether a pointer points to a base of a particular derived class instance using dynamic cast. Example:

```
struct X {
    virtual ~X() = default;
};
struct Y : X {};
struct Z : X {};



int main() {
    Y y;
    X* x = &y;
    if (Y* y = dynamic_cast<Y*>(x))
        ; // x indeed does point to (a base of) Y instance
          // and y now points to that Y instance
    if (Z* z = dynamic_cast<Z*>(x))
        ; // this is never reached, since x doesn't point to a base of Z
}
```

Whether the pointer is element of an array makes no difference.

Otherwise (i.e. if the class is not polymorphic), a pointer to a base of one class is indistinguishable from a pointer to a base (of same type) of another class, and thus in that case such check is not possible in general. You *could* implement it by storing type information of the derived type in a member of the base, but that can be complicated and probably not useful.

---

PS.

> ```
> class B : A {
>
> B ob;
>
> };
> ```

A class cannot have itself as a member.